# Migration issue Angular 7 to 9

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular9

I'm trying to migrate my application from 7 to 9, here the new IVY compiler in Angular 9 not compatible with library **angular-webstorage-service**
throws below error.

*ERROR in node_modules/angular-webstorage-service/src/storage-service.module.d.ts:9:22 - error NG6002: 
  Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.*

*This likely means that the library (angular-webstorage-service) which declares StorageServiceModule has not been processed correctly by s not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer versio update if so. Also consider checkn of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.*

Any ideas for Angular 9 compatability

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per **angular upgrade docs** [here](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l2)

[image]

So during the angular version upgrade the dependencies should be updated so they are
compatible for the upgraded version of angular.

The reason for the error is npm library *angular-webstorage-service* is **not** compatible for angular version 9.0.1.

As per *angular-webstorage-service docs* [here](https://github.com/dscheerens/ngx-webstorage-service#angular-version-compatibility-matrix) the *ngx-webstorage-service* is compatible for angular 9.

[image]

You should follow below commands

```
npm un angular-webstorage-service --save
npm i ngx-webstorage-service --save
```

This should resolve the issue.